# MySQL/InnoDB Plugin: Will NULL values for VARCHAR fields still take up storage spaces?

Tags: mysql, database, null, innodb, varchar

I'm using InnoDB Plugin in the Barracuda file format with:

`ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`

If I define a field as `VARCHAR(255)`, and then insert a record that has a `NULL` value for that field, will that record still use 255 bytes in storage for the `VARCHAR` field? Or will there be no wasted storage space?

On a related note, if I define a field as `INT` then presumably every record will still use 32 bits for that field even if the value for it is `NULL`. Is that correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should answer your question -

An SQL NULL value reserves one or two bytes in the record directory. Besides that, an SQL NULL value reserves zero bytes in the data part of the record if stored in a variable length column. In a fixed-length column, it reserves the fixed length of the column in the data part of the record. Reserving the fixed space for NULL values enables an update of the column from NULL to a non-NULL value to be done in place without causing fragmentation of the index page.

Please check more on [data-type storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) and [InnoDB physical row structure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-physical-record.html)

Comment: Please review the pending edits on this answer. The latter link is broken. The page is available via web.archive.org, but for those who want up-to-date info, see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html